# Health Connect update information in my app, only if I launch Google Fit app

Tags: android, healthconnect

I need to show the user the steps for the day. I decided to use Google Health Connect for this purpose. When I query StepsRecords, I get a list of recent records. But they are not up to date until I launch Google Fit.

Maybe I need to fill out a [google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1LFjbq1MOCZySpP5eIVkoyzXTanpcGTYQH26lKcrQUJo/viewform?edit_requested=true)? I still haven't figured out if this is mandatory or not?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val healthConnectClient = HealthConnectClient.getOrCreate(this)
        val someFlow = MutableStateFlow(0L)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            someFlow.emit(
                readStepsByTimeRange(
                    healthConnectClient,
                    Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofDays(1)),
                    Instant.now()
                )
            )
        }
        setContent {
            Text(text = someFlow.collectAsState().value.toString())
        }
    }

    suspend fun readStepsByTimeRange(
        healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient,
        startTime: Instant,
        endTime: Instant
    ): Long {
        return try {
            Log.d("TAG", "readStepsByTimeRange: begin")
            val response =
                healthConnectClient.readRecords(
                    ReadRecordsRequest(
                        recordType = StepsRecord::class,
                        timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime, endTime)
                    )
                )

            Log.d("TAG", "readStepsByTimeRange: response $response")

            response.records.map {
                Triple(it.startTime, it.endTime, it.count)
            }.onEach {
                Log.d("TAG", "readStepsByTimeRange: $it")
            }
            response.records.sumOf { it.count }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "readStepsByTimeRange: $e")
            return 0L
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How often are you querying the StepsRecord? Data isn't written to Health Connect automatically (apps need to write it), so it's likely that new data hasn't been written to Health Connect by Google Fit when you're querying it. Opening Fit is likely forcing the app to write, otherwise, new data will be written at a period determined by the app.

Comment: @Breana But then the question is, where does google fit get the data to record it in Health Connect? Google FIT API? But it's deprecated.

Comment: The Google Fit app records activity on both the watch and phone: https://www.google.com/fit/.